# Creating a mysql trigger with C++ in Qt

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, triggers

I am trying to create a SQL trigger for my database using Qt and I need help with the delimiter. I have no problem executing queries but when it comes to mysql commands like the delimiter how do I deal with it? I have used the  `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("MYSQL")` to connect with the driver and I haven't used other objects except from `QSqlDatabase` and `QSqlQuery`. Also my goal is to create the trigger through qt explicitly and not through the driver.
Can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `addDatabase` to add a database to the list of database connections using the driver type `MYSQL` and the connection name `myConnection`. After that you should set the connection's database name and open it. Then you can prepare a query for trigger and execute it:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "MYSQL","myConnection" );
db.setDatabaseName( "MydatabaseName" );
if( !db.open() )
{
    QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Failed to connect!"), tr("Error connecting to database") );
}

QSqlQuery qry(db);

qry.prepare( "CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE INSERT ON account "
             "FOR EACH ROW SET @sum = @sum + NEW.amount;" );

qry.exec();
```

Comment: Yeah thanks but my problem is when I have a block of commands, I need an IF()THEN...END IF; statement in my trigger which does not work unless I have a delimiter...